# Printing field by column with variable line field

Tags: awk

I have a command that returns an output similar to;

```
*************
* something *
*************

                                                     |     Header    |  Title  |
Column1|Column2         | Column3  |Column4| Column5 |Column6|Column7| Column8 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
val1    val2             val3       x y      i j      1(a) 2  1(a) 2  val4
val5    val6             val7       w x y z  i j k    2(b) 2  1(b) 1  val8
..
..

Total lines: xx
```

I want to just print column6 for example, but because the output is not fixed variable field by space, `awk '{print $x}'` won't work for me. I need a way to print output by defined column (eg. Column6 or Column8). Maybe printing the column6 field from the right which is field $5 from the right? Is there such a method to print from right rather than the default of all the command which count field from the left?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So, for the example input, is it correct that you only want to print the values `1(a) 2` and `2(b) 2`, which contain spaces themselves, and are preceded by columns also containing a variable number of spaces?  And is it correct that you can't rely on the format of `1(a) 2` because you might need to print column 4 (or 5, or 7, or 8) instead?  Can you rely on the location of the pipes in the line before the solid dashed line?

Comment: What's inside the brackets () is not important to me, the numbers outside the brackets on the left and right of the () is what I'm trying to extract out from the output of the command, the 1's and 2's. Because awk, sed and cut all look at fields counting from the left, column6, 7 and 8 can't be extracted with awk, sed and cut unless I can find a way to make these utilities look at fields counting from the right to left, because looking at the fields counting from right to left the field separated by spaces is always constant. Hope that explains the problem I'm facing.

Comment: Please update the question with the extra information and include what you expect from the sample data (making sure the description and sample match). You might need to include a couple more lines of data. You mention 6-8 in this comment; please make sure you cover the relevant bases in your update. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for being vague and not being clear. Sample data would look like this;

*************
* something *
*************

                                                     |     Header    |  Title  |
Column1|Column2         | Column3  |Column4| Column5 |Column6|Column7| Column8 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
val1    val2             val3       x y      i j      1(a) 2  1(a) 2  val4
val5    val6             val7       w x y z  i j k    2(b) 2  1(b) 1  val8
..
..

Total lines: xx

Comment: As I noted previously, please update the question — that is, use the edit link and change the content of the question.  Don't destroy what's already there, but add the extra information to the question.  One reason for this is that you can format the information — which you can't do in a comment.

Comment: Wish there is a way to attach txt file output for people to see.

Comment: There are ...  Or, at least, you can use copy'n'paste into the question, then select the material and use the **`{}`** button above the edit box to indent the material as 'code'.  It is presented in constant-width font and is what people normally use.  When you have enough reputation, it is possible to embed links to resources, but basic text files should be shown in the question — not as links.  Any links should be helpful rather than crucial to the question.

Comment: Is column 8 always present and always a simple value (no spaces in it) like the `val4` and `val8` examples shown in the question at the moment?  And it is the sample output — what you want the 'program' to produce from the input — that is currently least well specified.  The input is reasonably clear (apart from the content of column 8 — which I asked about at the start of this comment).

Answer (score 0):

Use `NF` for this

```
awk '{print $(NF-5)}'
```

This will print the 6th to last column for example

Comment: For the `val5` line, columns 11 and 12 should be printed; for the `val1` line, columns 8 and 9 should be printed.  It is not clear that you can rely on the structure of the last 5 fields — you might be OK printing `$(NF-5)` and `$(NF-4)`, but that is not certain.

Comment: Returned a fatal error;

$ cat dfile|awk '{print $(NF-5)}'
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: attempt to access field -4

Comment: Just playing with it more on your suggestion, it appears, I'll need to strip out the header and footer and just leave the below;

val1    val2             val3       x y      i j      1(a) 2  1(a) 2  val4
val5    val6             val7       w x y z  i j k    2(b) 2  1(b) 1  val8
..
..

Then using the awk '{print $(NF-5)}' gives me something close to what I want, just wondering if there is an easier and quicker way to extract the number to the left of the () as there is no spaces between the 1 and (.

Answer (score 0):

I have been solving similar problem. Assuming Column6 is all the time there, you can use following colon to find an index

```
echo "Column1|Column2|Column6|Column8" | sed 's/Column6.*//;s/[^|]\+//g' | wc -c
```

Then you can simply construct the awk query

```
X=$(echo ...)
SCRIPT="{ print \$${X}; }"
echo "Column1 |Column2 |Column6 |Column8" | awk "${SCRIPT}"
|Column6
```

Comment: Unfortunately, all it does is print out the heading;

Column1|Column2         | Column3  |Column4| Column5 |Column6|Column7| Column8

the numbers outside the brackets on the left and right of the () is what I'm trying to extract out from the output of the command, the 1's and 2's, is not printed out.

Answer (score 0):

**Rewrite** In Gnu awk:

```
$ cat program.awk
BEGIN  { FS="|" }
$0 ~ c {                                # process record with header
    split($0,a,"|")                     # split to get header indexes
    for(i in a) {                       # loop all column names
        gsub(/^ *| *$/,"",a[i])         # trim space off
        if(a[i]==c) ci=i                # ci is the one              
    }
    while(i=index($0,FS)) {             # form FIXEDWIDTHS to separate fields
        FIELDWIDTHS = FIELDWIDTHS i " "
        $0=substr($0,i+1)
    }
}
ci && $ci !~ /^-+$/ && $0=$ci           # implicit printing
```

Run it:

```
$ awk -v c="Column6" -f program.awk file
1(a) 2  
2(b) 2
```

If you want to edit the outputed column, the last row in `program.awk` is the place to do it. For example, let's imagine for a second that you'd like to loose the parenthesized part of `Column6`, you could for example create an action part with `{sub(/\(.*\)/,""); print}` for it.

Comment: Unfortunately all it does is print Column6, the numbers outside the brackets on the left and right of the () is what I'm trying to extract out from the output of the command, the 1's and 2's, is not printed out.

Comment: The reason for that behaviour was explained in the text body of the answer, on line one. This solution is a rewrite.